# Determination of ground state energy that has the same L and S values

Tags: physical-chemistry, quantum-chemistry

Determination of the energy of a multielectron atom in the ground state can be estimated using the atomic term symbol which involves the values ​​L, S and J. If an atom has the same L and S values ​​then the determination of the ground state is.......
Select one:

a. According to Hund's rule, for orbitals less than half full, the ground state is for the highest

b. According to Hund's rule, for orbitals filled more than half full, the ground state is for the lowest J

c. According to Pauli's rule, for orbitals filled less than half full, the ground state is for the lowest J

d. According to Pauli's rule, for orbitals filled more than half full, the ground state is for the highest J

e. According to Hund's rule, for orbitals filled less than half full, the ground state is for the lowest J

The Hund's rule is used to determine the ground state of an atom. I knew for the maximum multiplicity of S lies lowest in energy. And the term with the largest L value is lowest in energy, but the thing is, when L and S were in the same value, the one that determine this is the J value which is the highest J value for half filled, and lowest J value for >half filled

Considering the question, i have no idea which were the answer, the a or b? or am i wrong throughougth? can you give me some resources to help me understand this more?

Comment: I'm not sure you stated Hund's rules properly. Stated briefly they are (a) max number of unpaired electrons lowest energy (b) for same spin multiplicity, largest orbital ang mom usually lowest in energy (c) less that half filled level, lowest J usually lowest in energy.